# How to fix 'TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not NoneType' error

Tags: python

I'm learning Python, but I am using 3.x, and the exercise is 2.x. I have already fixed some of the errors, but this one has stumped me.

I've searched various forums but I haven't been able to figure it out.

```
def activity03test():
    tests = [[[1,2,3,4] , 2] , [[1,3,5,7] , 0] , [[2,4,6,9] , 3] , [[1,2,6,7] , 2]]
    print ("\nStarting Test 3...")
    for i in tests:
        return_value = activity03(i[0])
        if return_value != i[1]:
            print ("Failed: Input: %s\nExpected: %d\nReceived: %d" % (str(i[0]), i[1], return_value))
            return -1
        else:
            print ("Correct:\t%s\t=\t%d" % (str(i[0]), return_value))
    return 0
```

The error is occurring in this line:

```
print ("Failed: Input: %s\nExpected: %d\nReceived: %d" % (str(i[0]), i[1], return_value))
```

Comment: Evidently `return_value is None` - you haven't shown `activity03`, so we can't tell you why.

Comment: Nvm. I fixed it. I had to add some code to my other program - activity03. My bad.

Comment: Then I'd suggest just deleting this question.

Comment: @Cobrastar98, please if you have fixed your problem with my solution mark it, otherwise add your solution or delete question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that function *activity03* returns *None*. 
Your code fails because %d is the placeholder for numbers, and NoneType is not admitted. 
In order to fix this problem you can use the *format* function to fill up your string.

Check the code below:

```
print("Failed: Input: {}\nExpected: {}\nReceived: {}".format(str(i[0]), i[1], return_value))
```

Otherwise, if you want maintaine the string formatting as it, you can add a condition in the if statement above, like this:

```
for i in tests:
    return_value = activity03(i[0])
    if return_value != i[1] and return_value is not None:
        print ("Failed: Input: %s\nExpected: %d\nReceived: %d" % (str(i[0]), i[1], return_value))
        return -1
    else:
        ...
```